# DataTables Editor -Button extension How to disable a specific button on selecting a row?

Tags: button, datatables, editor

Using DataTable ( v 1.10) with the Editor plugin,   and the button extension,
I am trying to disable the Remove button upon row selection when a field in the row has a value > 0

```
 var nb_users;
 var table = $('#groups').DataTable( {
     dom: 'Bftlp',
     select: true,
     ...
     buttons: [
        { extend: "create", editor: editor },
        { extend: "edit",  editor: editor },
        { extend: "remove",  editor: editor }
     ]
  });

  table
     .on( 'select', function ( e, dt, type, indexes ) {
        var rowData = table.rows( indexes ).data().toArray();
        nb_users = rowData[0].nb_users;
        if (nb_users > 0) {
           $('.buttons-remove').addClass('disabled');
        }
      } )
      .on( 'deselect', function ( e, dt, type, indexes ) {
          if (nb_users > 0) {
             $('.buttons-remove').removeClass('disabled');
          }
      } );
```

but it does not disable/enable the Remove button at all...

I don't know if the Editor extension trigger these buttons before or after the .on('select') ..
Is there any coll way to  set specific triggers for these Editor buttons ?

thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

You Can acheive this by following code

```
table.on( 'select', function () {
    var nb_users = table.row({ selected: true }).data().nb_users;
    if (nb_users > 0) {
       table.button(2).disable(); // 0 for Create, 1 for Edit, 2 for Remove
    }
} );
```

You can check example from [This Datatable Example](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/api/enable)